# How to populate nested objects having _id in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a field in mongoose model named Details as -

```
school: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "School" }]
```

I have data saved in my database as-

```
school:[62a1c7c85808f632c8bca91d,62a1c7c85808f632c8bca914]
```

How do I populate school where only _id is stored?

Comment: Using `.populate('school')`?

Comment: `await Detail.find({}).populate('school').exec()`